# ¿Cómo ocultar la Url de un tabs?

Tags: jquery

Tengo realizado un tabs con jQuery simple bonito pero el aspecto de mostrar la Url daña lo bonito:

```
localhost/tabs/tab.html#tab1
```

Si pasan el puntero por encima de los enlaces del tabs observaran que mostrara la siguiente url `localhost/tabs/tab.html#tab1` y `localhost/tabs/tab.html#tab2`

**¿Cómo puedo modificar el código jQuery para no mostrar aquellas Url como las puedo ocultar?**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tab-content").hide();
  $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
  $(".tab-content:first").show();

  $("ul.tabs li").click(function()
       {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tab-content").hide();

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Ejemplo en ejecución

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tab-content").hide();
  $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
  $(".tab-content:first").show();

  $("ul.tabs li").click(function()
       {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tab-content").hide();

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="main-tabs">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a href="#tab1">Descripción</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">Contenido del curso</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3">Preguntas y respuestas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab4">Marcadores</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="wrap tbs">
      <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
      </div>
      <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto y despues me dices. Cambie la propiedad **href** por **data-ref**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="main-tabs">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li><a data-ref="#tab1">Descripción</a></li>
      <li><a data-ref="#tab2">Contenido del curso</a></li>
      <li><a data-ref="#tab3">Preguntas y respuestas</a></li>
      <li><a data-ref="#tab4">Marcadores</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="wrap tbs">
      <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
      </div>
      <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
   $(a[data-ref]').attr('href','href="javascript:;')
    .on('click', function(){
       var id = $(this).attr('data-ref');
       $(id).tab('show');
    });
});
</script>
```